# Simulate click event in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

Is there any way to simulate a click event in AS3? I'm trying this:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, true, false));
```

But click event isn't trigger it.

Comment: What element are you trying to simulate the click to?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you are listening for `MouseEvent.CLICK` then dispatch `MouseEvent.CLICK`. You are now dispatching `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN`

```
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK));
```

Comment: I am curious, is the dispatch handler of Flash PREVENTING the firing of the MOUSE_DOWN event?

Comment: @eLouai if you are listening for a `MOUSE_DOWN` event, Flash will not handle `CLICK` events, and vice versa. The `MOUSE_DOWN` event is fired when you click the mouse, the `MOUSE_UP` when you release then mouse. The `CLICK` event is equivalent to a `MOUSE_DOWN` followed by a `MOUSE_UP`. However, dispatching `MOUSE_DOWN` and `MOUSE_UP` separately will not fire a `CLICK` event

Comment: As per Adobe's documents they state it clearly ... "For a click event to occur, it must always follow this series of events in the order of occurrence: mouseDown event, then mouseUp. The target object must be identical for both of these events; otherwise the click event does not occur. Any number of other mouse events can occur at any time between the mouseDown or mouseUp events; the click event still occurs." but unfortunately I seem to up unable to affect it, so either the system is listening on ANOTHER event stream that it reacts to, or there is a bug.

Answer (score 4):

You must dispatch a MouseEvent.CLICK event.

```
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.CLICK, true, false));
```

Answer (score 0):

To simulate a CLICK event you need first to dispatch:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, true, false));
```

followed by a:

```
element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, true, false));
```

On the MOUSE_UP event the handler will then issue a click event (if the mouse is OVER the element, so you may need to set the mouse_x and mouse_y variables in the dispatched event.